# Binomial nomenclature: italic or slanted?

Tags: typography, italic, slanted

I have read about the difference between italic and slanted fonts in TeX: how do the commands differ, as well as the effect when applied on the fonts; but it seems that there has not been much emphasis on "which to use". For instance, should I use `\sl` or `\it` (or LaTeX equivalent `textsl` and `textit`) for binomial nomenclature? I guess it does not matter as long as consistent font is used throughout the article, but I do wonder if there were any conventions on this, or if anyone has ever written a similar scientific article and what did they choose.[image: above: slanted; below: italic]

Comment: For a start: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68931/what-is-the-difference-between-italics-and-slanted-text. Not all fonts have italics and slanted, sometimes \textsl is a synonym for \textit. BTW you should not use neither \sl nor \it, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc. There might be a convention on binomial nomenclature. You might want to define a wrapper macro to change the behaviour consistently.

Comment: @CampanIgnis `\it` and `\sl` are actually what TeXBook has taught me (yeah, I'm starting from plain TeX); would not use them in LaTeX of course ;)

Comment: For me it's very simple: I never use slanted.

Comment: @egreg If one created it, there is use of it.

Comment: @Futarimiti There's plenty of useless inventions… :-)